# Volume of critical points decreases under symmetric decreasing rearrangement

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, geometric-measure-theory, calculus-of-variations

In the lecture note http://www.math.utoronto.ca/almut/rearrange.pdf, it was stated that the volume of the set of critical points decreases under symmetric decreasing rearrangement. It seems so obvious however I cannot prove it.  There is also deleted topic in mathoverflow which stated exactly the same question as mine. 
Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: well, a critical point is a change from (nonstrict) increasing to (nonstrict) decreasing, or vice versa, right? But a monotone function gets rid of the nonstrictness.  You are left with only strict changes.